# Eclipse Option not available : Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, jarsigner

I have created my Google market publisher private keystore. Now I want to Export the UNSIGNED apk using eclipse but I am not able to find the option : Export Unsigned Application Package.

All I can see is this option : Export Android Application, when I right click on project and click Export. If I use this option, I am not able to use jarsigner as it gives an error indicating the apk is already signed.

I am assuming the export option above is exporting a (dubug key) signed apk and not an unsigned one.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on the Project -> Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package.

By the way, if you want to sign with self signed certificate / keystore, you can use the Project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package.